# Four Satipatthanas

Tags: anapanasati, satipatthana

In [this Buddhadasa Bhikkhu Dhamma Talk](https://soundcloud.com/buddhadasa/9112-3-dhamma-questions-answers), Ajahn Buddhadasa and Santikaro Bhikkhhu explained at around minute 51:30 - 54:00 that the four Satipatthanas are always investigated.

As far as I understood, the four tetrads are done in a sequence, without choosing. After rapture arises in Kayanupassana, rapture becomes the object of meditation, and the transition from kaya to vedana happens.

May one clarify their statement given in that recording? How is it done in daily life in whatever posture, if the arising of rapture etc. require deep meditation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92611/discussion-on-question-by-val-four-satipatthanas).

Comment: Did you listen to his explanation? He said we contemplate the tetrad we need to contemplate - to be mindful of what we need to be mindful of. Humans are not robots. He said we do move from lower to higher overall, in the big picture. He said it's already been written, so now we just apply it. Yes it can be done formally, he says, but in this answer he says do it walking, sitting, standing, lying down.

Answer (score 2):

> **As far as I understood, the four tetrads are done in a sequence, without choosing. After rapture arises in Kayanupassana, rapture
>   becomes the object of meditation, and the transition from kaya to
>   vedana happens.**

The above is how I interpret what was said from from 51:30. What was said was the previous satipatthana supports the next satipatthana. In other words, developing calming the body supports the arising of & profound sensitivity of rapture.

> **the four Satipatthanas are always investigated.**

This statement by Santikaro was vague. It all depends on how profoundly or how shallowly the practise is. In daily life, the satipatthana practise will generally be quite shallow or superficial (unless a person has previously developed samadhi, which they can enter, at will, while sitting on a bus or in a boring office meeting). Once there is a question about "daily life", the answer will not be particularly profound. For example, in daily life, the 1st tetrad will generally not be developed to give rise to rapture of the 2nd tetrad. Reaching rapture is generally has the requirement of formal retreat. In daily life, the framework in MN 10 rather than MN 118 would probably be best followed.

Comment: Thanks DD, fine answer as always. Speaking of MN10, what is meant by contemplating externally? Also, the title with 'Mindfulness in all postures' refers here to bare awareness, correct? Because clear comprehension is listed immediately after the postures.

Comment: I assume contemplating externally means to contemplate body, feeling, mind & dhamma (truth) in external objects. For example, visualize external objects are breathing, are controlled by citta (mental states), are impermanent, are not-self, etc.

Comment: Mindfulness means to remember to have right view in all postures. Clear-comprehension means to thoroughly understand with wisdom with all postures. It does not mean "bare awareness". In fact, it is the opposite of "bare awareness". For example, a small child ignorantly looking non-judgmentally at the ocean with bare awareness and thus not understanding the dangers of the ocean cannot have “sampajana”. I wrote about sampajana, here: https://dhammadhatu.wordpress.com/2018/12/04/dependent-origination-sankhara-part-2/

Comment: Since you were listening to Buddhadasa, you can read Buddhasa's views on mindfulness & clear-comphrension (which I agree with & regard as very essential reading), here: https://www.dhammatalks.net/Books/Bhikkhu_Buddhadasa_Natural_Cure_for_Spiritual_Disease2.htm

Comment: Thanks, I was only confused about the Body Posture part because it sounded like being aware of actions. You already explained sati sampajanna to me. Anyways, thanks as always DD. Kind regards